# Android: Read Website Table into Table/ListView

Tags: java, android, html, sql

I have been researching this, but I cannot find a simple way to read a table from a website and translate it into a table/list View which can basically be interpreted in terms of numbers and operated on(via calculations normally). Essentially, I want to grab numbers out of a website and parse them to recognized integers.

I realize this will use SQL or some sort of HTML parser, but any guidance to a tutorial page or some sample code would be highly appreciated. I need this as a part of my android application, so using Java. The website would not just contain the table's image, it would be a full page.[image: Sample Web Page/Table to Parse. I would need the info in these columns to convert.]

Thank you in advance.

Sample Web Page (Table is blurred, but the columns will be like this)

Comment: check out [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and see if it helps for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to get the websites HTML source code and pass it through a DOM parser. You need following classes for that: `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder`. After the parsing process you get a `Document` object. Every tag, attribute name, attribute value etc. of your HTML source code is stored in there, so are your needed integer values. You can get these values by accessing its nodes. Take a look at this link how to parse a DOM document and get its values: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/. But use your fetched HTML source coude instead of the file input:

```
String htmlSourceCode = "<html>blabla</html>"; //your fetched HTML source code
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlSourceCode.getBytes()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```